# Typescript optional chaining with check on the last argument

Tags: typescript, optional-chaining

I have an if statement that looks like this:

```
if ("arg3" in arg1.arg2 && customFunction(arg1.arg2.arg3)) {}
```

Now any of the arguments can be undefined so I wanted to use optional chaining:

```
if ("arg3" in arg1?.arg2? && customFunction(arg1.arg2.arg3)) {}
```

The problem here is I cannot check `arg2` with `arg2?.` or `arg2?` because Typescript expects an additional argument or thinks I want to use a conditional operator. So I'm wondering if the only way to get this if statement working is with:

```
if (arg1?.arg2 && "arg3" in arg1.arg2 && customFunction(arg1.arg2.arg3)) {}
```

I've had several situations where I try to use optional chaining and needed to check the last argument. I'm quite new to programming so I'm happy if somebody can tell me how to write it correctly or can point me to documentation which explains why I cannot or should not have the last argument as optional.

EDIT1: For those wondering about the types of arg1, 2 and 3:
In my situation I have a form you can fill to create an automation for a specific process. You have general Information and an Input and Output which can be of type SMB or Email.

the interface looks something like this:

```
process: {
  processName: string,
  description: string
  input: smbInterface | emailInterface
  output: smbInterface | emailInterface
}

smbInterface: {
  username: string,
  password: string,
  uncPath: string
}

emailInterface: {
  username: string,
  password: string,
  domain: string
}
```

When submitting the form I check if any of the fields is empty or null. When checking `uncPath` like this I get an error "is possibly undefined":

```
if (isEmpty(process.input.uncPath)) {}
```

So I change it to:

```
if ("uncPath" in process?.input && isEmpty(process.input.uncPath)) {}
```

Still getting the undefined error so I change it to:

```
if (process.input && "uncPath" in process.input && isEmpty(process.input.uncPath)) {}
```

This works but I wonder if I can simplify it to something like this:

```
if ("uncPath" in process?.input? && isEmpty(process.input.uncPath)) {}
```

Obviously with `process?.input?` Typescript thinks I want to use a conditional operator so I'm looking for another way.

I hope this clears it up a bit. Sorry if I was unclear (and maybe still am).

EDIT2: Apparently my clearer example is missing something which I currently don't know what it is. As VLAZ pointed out in his comment it should be working with:

```
if ("uncPath" in process?.input && isEmpty(process.input.uncPath)) {}
```

For now T.J. Crowders answer solves my question of how to check the last argument of an optional chain with nullish coalescing.

Comment: The operator is [`.?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), you can't just have the question mark and it doesn't make sense at the end of the chain. What are you expecting to get if `arg1` is defined but doesn't have an `arg2` property? Do you want e.g. `arg1?.arg2 || default`?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what is expected? It seems like `arg1?.arg2?.arg3 != null && customFunction(arg1.arg2.arg3)` should work but I cannot be sure. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTk4oBzAJgH4AuQiygZgeRAFcBbAI2gC+yAPTCARFz7QxyBHBDJ+5EOg4B7EAFouAGx3AAzgAtkANzg7OEIgKIATCAh0UUCDQbDkqARkYZskLCIEADc9o7OUCgwnCAIYMAaspweatwAYrHxiSAAFAAejJL8UACUjLxqajoQ8mFEwDDIuczetAB0zHSdVCzIAIQAvBycesgAZOPJqRlZCRotPj00yyylpYS2QA)

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, it would be useful to know the type of `arg1.arg2.arg3`.

Comment: I've edited my question. I hope my situation becomes a bit clearer. Tell me if it's still unclear.

Comment: `if ("uncPath" in process?.input && isEmpty(process.input.uncPath)) {}` [seems to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewMYQM6qgXigbwFBRRiIroByAhgLYQBcUqwcAlgHYDmANAVACZpIWYYMwSt6jFhx5swAV2ASqAIwCSrYBDgAzCiigAfKBCoVmAG3WadeiDwQL5ihiqtbd+oybOWN723gAvnh4oJAuan42+tj4hHKoWqzUdAxMbFw8YBToAO4IcLwS6Rzc8axIMBTAABbFUuxBIWHQ3hZu0dCxPAlJKfUZZUQ5qPmFA6U8vAimbBONwXj8SOYUcNDachUiYlDMqACiVMIgABSyCvMAlPTKCAjmEBSsANwhy6vrUEhijEQkaFQ9HgyEBbzwzG0UFOACItpVqjUYXtWP9QegAPwAOguwCgADJ8XtDsdQKdiOjUDjWE4sfCqrUrldcIEgA)

Comment: Thank you for your help. In that case my example in the question is missing something which I currently don't know what it is. In my code, input can be undefined for some reason. I'll adjust the example if I find out what it is. For now T.J. Crowders answer solves my question of how to check the last argument of an optional chain. (nullish coalescing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, with just `?` you're starting the conditional operator.¹ The optional chaining operator is `?.` (the `.` isn't, er, optional).

There's another problem with that condition, which is that if `arg1` is nullish, the result of `arg?.arg2` is `undefined`, and you can't use `in` on `undefined`.

You could use nullish coalescing:

```
if ("arg3" in (arg1?.arg2 ?? {}) && customFunction(arg1.arg2.arg3)) {}
```

but I think I'd rather do what's in your question since it short-circuits earlier:

```
if (arg1?.arg2 && "arg3" in arg1.arg2 && customFunction(arg1.arg2.arg3)) {}
```

but that's only reliable if we know (presumably from type information) that `arg1.arg2` won't have a falsy value other than `undefined` or `null`.

---

¹ The conditional operator (`?:`) is **a** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands, just like a binary operator accepts two and a unary operator accepts one), and currently it's JavaScript's only ternary operator, but that could change. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clearing up my misunderstanding that ternary operator != conditional operator. Makes total sense now, haha. I've fixed the question.

Comment: @SeanA.S.Mengis - Oh, I think "misunderstanding" is rather a strong way to put it. :-D Most people call it "the ternary operator." But I like to correct that where I can... Happy coding!